# Magento 2.3.1 customer grid sorting issue

Tags: admin, grid, cache, redis, magento2.3.1

I am using magento 2.3.1.

I am having this strange issue only in admin>customer grid

No matter which column I choose to sort the results are always the same.

It happens only in this grid.

[image: ID sort ascending]

[image: ID sort descending]

What I tried:

1. reindex all indexers, several times
2. checked Redis conf, removed, reinstalled again
3. Checked Opcache settings, disabled and enabled back
4. Used nginx standalone, used Nginx as proxy pass with Apache
5. Reboot server several time
6. Magento caches are disabled, recleared several times, recopliled and redeploy
7. Cleared ui_bookmark table

Nothing from these helped.  The only thing I noticed is that on local server with apache only it works with no problem.

Also when this started, when I tried to install a new module, although module was istalled fine, upgraded and compiled when I went to admin I couldn't find it anywhere.

Again in local wasn't this problem. I think that these two are related.

> UPDATE

After making some operations to server and needed to restart all services like Nginx, php-fpm, Redis, varnish, elastic magento customer grid started to work fine again.

But after working in admin about 2 days again the customer grid isn't sorting.

I am sure that is definitely some cache problem....Something is caching this particular grid....I am using Redis 5. Maybe I switch to 4?

Any help or ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: What about request in the network tab of your browser? Is data present in response?

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau. I see: `http://example.com/admin/mui/index/render/key/a70f1877ef4497ab4d91b261bdc84e59fd55cfa9c4477de093b6585044aeda24/?namespace=customer_listing&search=&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=100&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=entity_id&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=desc&isAjax=true` and `http://example.com/admin/mui/bookmark/save/key/cebf3f2d676c37e2259d0e4964b2d5daf27620c32e8010e7e255929dd375cb05/?isAjax=true` GET and POST. These only the first time I press in column sort....If I press again I get no data in network.

Comment: Is a data obtained in first request are the same as a data in the analogical request on the server without that issue? I think if the data from the first request was broken it can broke whole ui-grid.

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau data is the same....I haven't figure out why this is happening. I updated my post with new finds....Also as far as I know when Ajax post the request isn't rendering the right results in grid....but in data is fine...I think is some kind of cache....

Comment: I faced same issue after upgrade from 2.3. I get it resolved by upgrading it again :( No changes to code nothing, Still had old instance where sorting not working. No words for magento :(

Comment: @Vivek what you mean upgrade again? Reinstall magento?

Comment: Dont follow my answer. It already sounds stupid. As I said I faced same issue when I upgrade store from 2.3. I debugged but doesn't succeed. So I forget that and today I upgrade main instance with same procedure but issue doesnt reproduced. As I said It sounds stupid.

Comment: For my end sometimes is fixed. But when you start working in admin then it breaks again....So I think you should get same results after working in admin....

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem in Magento 2.2.8.

The problem is that the controller returns the same results, sorted by ID (or not, not sure).

After digging into this I found out that a problem in this file:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/GroupManagement.php
```

Inside `getLoggedInGroups` method:

```
$groupNameSortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
            ->setField('customer_group_code')
            ->setAscendingDirection()
            ->create();
```

Here, the sort is always set to AscendingDirection (`setAscendingDirection`) and after setting this sorting to search criteria `->addSortOrder($ groupNameSortOrder)`

I fixed this temporarily by simply overriding this file and deleting the line with `->addSortOrder($ groupNameSortOrder)`

Small guide:

1. Create new module.
2. File: app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <!-- Customer Admin Grid Sorting fix -->
        <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\GroupManagement"
                    type="VENDOR\MODULE\Model\Customer\GroupManagement" />
    </config>
   ```
3. File: app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Model/Customer/GroupManagement.php

   filterBuilder
                ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
                ->setConditionType('neq')
                ->setValue(self::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
                ->create();
            $groupAll[] = $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
                ->setConditionType('neq')
                ->setValue(self::CUST_GROUP_ALL)
                ->create();
            $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                ->addFilters($notLoggedInFilter)
                ->addFilters($groupAll)
                ->create();
            return $this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you! But it isn't working for me....Tried with module and directly to core file...No luck. @Игорь Колчин are you sure it fixed for you?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried to run commands from cli: bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento setup:di:compile ?
You can check which results returns magento in devtools: https://prnt.sc/ngc0mw
Do both requests return the same data, or they are different and sorted?

Comment: I run upgrade and compile....it didn't help...Also in network when I sort I don't have your screen. I only have one ?namespace=customer request. Above I have only ?isAjax=true with empty results. If I refresh the page I get the two requests. Then when try to sort I get again only one request and empty Ajax

Comment: Try to sort different column. For example sort column with emails twice and check requests

Comment: all columns have same result....Nothing is changing....Also I tried to remove some of them...Problem still there

Comment: Works for me, thanks for the fix